# Annotate по полю несвязанной модели

Tags: python, django, аннотации

Использую Django 1.11. Вот модели:

```
class UserPromoCode(models.Model):
    promo_code = models.ForeignKey(PromoCode, related_name="user_promo_code")

class PromoCode(models.Model):
    code = models.CharField(max_length=20)
```

Нужно получить такую выборку в один или два запроса к БД:

```
promocodes = PromoCode.objects.all()
for p in promocodes:
   p.assigned_times = UserPromoCode.objects.filter(user_promo_code=p.code).count()
```

Проблема в том, что поле PromoCode.code не уникально, по этому я не могу использовать связь и выполнить `PromoCode.objects.annontate(assigned_times=Count('user_promo_code'))`, что будет аналогом такой выборки:

```
promocodes = PromoCode.objects.all()
for p in promocodes:
   p.assigned_times = p.user_promo_code.count()
```

Предполагаю, это должно быть что-то вроде `PromoCode.objects.annontate(assigned_times=Count(???))`.

Comment: А в чём собственно вопрос? Можете конкретнее сформулировать проблему?

Comment: Не получается одним запросом получить промокоды вместе с количеством юзер кодов, в которых такой же код. Понятно, что так не сработает, но может так понятнее (на место 'code' должен подставится код каждого промокода): PromoCode.objects.annontate(assigned_times=Count(UserCode.objects.filter(user_code='code')))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел способ как это сделать:

```
from django.db.models import OuterRef, Subquery
from django.db.models.functions import Coalesce

user_promo_codes = UserPromoCode.objects.filter(promo_code__code=OuterRef('code')).values('promo_code__code')
user_promocode_counts = upks.annotate(c=Count('*')).values('c')

PromoCode.objects.annotate(assigned_times=Coalesce(Subquery(user_promocode_counts), 0)
```

Coalesce используется потому, что user_promocode_counts там, где должен быть 0 получал None.